# Post data always empty with PHPunit

Tags: laravel, post, phpunit, lumen

I am using Lumen 5.4 and any PHPUnit tests that POST to applicable endpoints don't contain any data or headers.  I've used both the `json` and regular `call` functions without success.  Here is an example of some tests I've used:

```
public function testLoginUser(){
    $user = ["username"=>"user", "password"=>"password"];
    $this->json('POST', '/login', $user)->seeJson(['success'=>true]);
}
```

Yet when I look at the `Request` data sent to the controller (`public function loginUser(Request $request)`, it's all blank.

It works fine when I utilize Postman.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Per the link below, it appears that the issue has to do with a change in Lumen 5.4 for handling requests.  Downgrading to 5.3 fixes it for now.

Comment: This could be related - https://laravel-news.com/request-object-changes-in-lumen-5-4

Comment: Yeah, it definitely seems like an issue with 5.4.  I downgraded to 5.3 and the unit tests now work again.  Weirdly, `dev-master` still has the same problem.  Thanks for the link.